# Small electrical water heater

Tags: resistors, water, heater

When I was much younger than my current 64 years of age, I saw water heaters made using simply two single electrical 110 V wires and some form of a connection between the two, to simply stick in a cup of water to heat it up for instant cocoa or coffee.

Can anyone with electrical background tell me of a proven given method of building one of these simple contraptions?

I have done a search all over the internet using "hot shot" or "cup water heater" and cannot find any reference to one.

Comment: If the ones described [here](https://epn.org/top-10-best-travel-immersion-water-heater-reviews/) are what you are looking for, try googling "immersion water heater". I would buy, not make, BTW.

Comment: not recommended.  electrode type water steamers rely on salt added for evaoration rate on these "steamers"   Wheres immersion heaters use wire heater by conduction. Similarly electrodes inserted at opposite ends of wieners inject current in an uncontrolled rapid rate.  Better think of something better. Corrosion issues.

Comment: Web search suicide shower

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are talking about one of these:

[image: Immersion Cup Heater]

This one is listed on Amazon at:

[Immersion Heater URL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M0Q84BR)

It is simply a resistive heating element inside a metal (looks like Aluminum) tube with some sort of insulator material between the element and the tube.  Probably woven glass fiber.  It likely also has a thermal limit switch, perhaps a resettable one, that will shut it down if the cup boils dry.  That would help prevent a self-destructive situation or possibly a fire.

The heating element is likely nichrome wire and its length is calculated such that the desired amount of power is generated at 110V, probably 250-300 Watts.

Search for : "Norpro Instant Immersion Heater" and you should be able to find one like is shown in the image.

Answer (score 2):

Immersion heaters using heating elements are still widely available. They’re constructed using a a resistive element (typically nichrome wire) encased in a metal tube. The element insulated from the tube by nonconducting spacer material such as MgO powder. This shows the general scheme:

[image]

From here: http://m.heaterfactory.com/tubular-heater/formed-tubular-heater/industrial-straight-tubular-heater-element.html

I’ll assume you can find those on your own; otherwise it’s a shopping question that’s frowned upon here at EE-SE.

What’s *not* available (or at least, shouldn’t be) are the type that use conduction through the liquid. These are nothing more than a pair of electrodes spaced some distance apart in a holder. They work by passing current between the electrodes, creating a large I2R drop and thus heating the liquid. These are super dangerous as they can be a shock and fire hazard.

If you have some time to waste, here’s a video link of one of those sketchy conduction heaters in action, ‘overclocked’ a bit, as one does (from Diode Gone Wild): https://youtu.be/jS4GTACKETg

tl; dw: with the heater running at 400V, even a small amount of ionic salt in the water makes the current reach dangerous levels. Bloody hell!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. Everything from where to buy one, all the way to how to build one even. I couldn't have received better replies from a better bunch.